# Bash Exclude dot-dash prefixes

Tags: bash

Can't seem to crack this one.

I have a bash script to search a folder and exclude certain file types.

```
list=`find . -type f ! \( -name "*data.php" -o -name "*.log" -o -iname "._*" -o -path "*patch" \)`
```

I want to exclude files which start with dot-dash ._ but the above just refuses to work.

Here's some more of the script, but I am still getting files copied with start with ._

O/S is CentOS 5.3

```
    list=`find . -type f ! \( -name "*data.php" -o -name "*.log" -o -iname "._*" -o -path "*patch" \)`
    for a in $list; do
       if [ ! -f "$OLDFOL$a" ]; then
            cp --preserve=all --parents $a $UPGFOL
          continue
       fi
       diff $a "$OLDFOL$a" > /dev/null
       if [[ "$?" == "1" ]]; then
            # exists & different so copy
            cp --preserve=all --parents $a $UPGFOL
       fi
    done
```

Comment: works for me (on GNU find version 4.1.20)

Comment: You mean dot-underscore?

Comment: Even works on WinXP/Cygwin with findutils 4.5.9. So, what is it that is not working?

Comment: might be that you need to use '._*' to prevent globbing by the shell

Comment: Fredrik: might be that you have to check with reality first? `echo "*"` will tell you

Answer (score 2):

First -- don't do it that way.

```
files="`find ...`"
```

splits names on whitespace, meaning that `Some File` becomes two files, `Some` and `File`. Even splitting on newlines is unsafe, as valid UNIX filenames can contain `$'\n'` (any character other than `/` and null is valid in a UNIX filename). Instead...

```
getfiles() {
  find . -type f '!' '(' \
    -name '*data.php' -o \
    -name '*.log' -o \
    -iname "._*" -o \
    -path "*patch" ')' \
    -print0
}
while IFS= read -r -d '' file; do
  if [[ ! -e $orig_dir/$file ]] ; then
     cp --preserve=all --parents "$file" "$dest_dir"
     continue
  fi
  if ! cmp -q "$file" "$orig_dir/$file" ; then
     cp --preserve=all --parents "$file" "$dest_dir"
  fi
done < <(getfiles)
```

The above does a number of things right:

- It is safe against filenames containing spaces or newlines.
- It uses `cmp -q`, not `diff`. `cmp` exits immediately when a change is made, rather than needing to calculate the delta between two files, and is thus far faster.

Read [BashFAQ #1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001), [UsingFind](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/UsingFind), and [BashPitfalls #1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_i_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29) to understand some of the differences between this and the original.

Also -- I've validated that this correctly excludes filenames which start with `._` -- but the original version did too. Perhaps what you *really* want is to exclude filenames matching `*._*` rather than `._*`?